Game Theory Pure strategies in a sequential game with perfect information
Suppose there are two companies, A and B, each produce and sell a product. Each wants to increase their market share. Company A intends to do some of either:
– Spend 10% of profits on advertising,
– Reduce the price of the product, or
– Give a free gift on purchase of the product.
Company B intends to do one of either:
– Spend 5% of profits on advertising, or
– Reduce the price of the product.
The number of pure strategies that A has is 7. The number of Pure strategies that B has is 2 (when playing simultaneously. Now suppose A goes first and then B can decide what choice to make. How many pure strategies does B have ? I believe the answer to be 14 as for each choice of pure strategy A plays we have two options. apparently this is not correct. Can someone please explain why.

As the game is of perfect information, a pure strategy for B is a list of what strategy B will play for each of A's options. A has $7$ options and B has to decide between $2$ choices for each option, so there are $2^7$ possibilities for B's list.

If however I have full knowledge of what A plays then as player B I only need to respond to one choice of strategy and so I only need to make a choice between two strategies for each of A's choices. i.e If I am B and I see player A played strategy 1 ( assuming he has numbered his 7 strategies) then for each choice I am making a choice between two elements. Why would I need to create a list for all strategies ?

@JohnSmith Yes, you will only have to respond to one of A's options, but the game hasn't started yet so you don't know which. Imagine you're going for an interview. You know you'll be asked one of three questions. You won't have to give an answer until you've heard the question, but you still need to plan in advance how you will answer each of the questions that might be asked. That's a strategy.

thanks that clarifies things

Apparently $B$ has $2$ responses to each of $A$'s $7$ actions (though I am not sure whether "do nothing" might be an eighth), and can combine these possible responses in any pattern.
Since, before $A$ acts, $B$ does not know what will $A$ will do, this amounts to $2^7$ strategies for $B$.

Since B has to do "some of either" he must perform at least one action and hence 7 strategies not 8.
